# Insert file to input from another input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a jquery DataTable which can have multiple rows. I populate each row using a modal. Each row may or may not have an attachment based on the values selected and this table is inside a form. Now the problem is I am unable to attach files in the Datatable so I have created a hidden div in which I am creating input fields of file type each time the user want to attach a file in the DataTable. Below is the code for that

```
var attachmentInput = $("#hiddenDiv").find("input[id='prototype']").clone()
            var tempInputId = "Visa Attachment_" + fileCounter
            attachmentInput.prop("id",tempInputId)
            attachmentInput.prop("name",tempInputId)
            attachmentInput.appendTo("#hiddenDiv")
```

Now what I want is that whenever the user tries to attach a file in the modal the file should be attached to the input field created in the hiddenDiv. I am trying the following code to do it.

```
$("#"+tempInputId).after($('#visaDetails')[0].files[0]);
```

My main requirement is that when a user attaches a file in the modal it should be attached to the dynamically created input element of file type.... Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't move files from one FileInput to another, due to security concerns.What you might try is a button in the modal that uses javascript to "click" the file input.

Comment: Wow neil thanks for pointing that out ... what i did was inside the modal i created a button which onclick i am now creating an input element and then calling the click function on that newly created element .... below is the code .. hope it explains how i solved my problem..

Answer (score 0):

Wow neil thanks for pointing that out ... what i did was inside the modal i created a button which onclick i am now creating an input element and then calling the click function on that newly created element and in the DataTable just saving a dummy value which is of no actual use ... the newly created input element acts as a input element of the form .... below is the code .. hope it explains how i solved my problem..

```
var fileCounter = 0

    var tempInputId 

         $('#visaDetails').on('click', function(){


                var attachmentInput = $("#hiddenDiv").find("input[id='prototype']").clone()

            tempInputId = "visaAttachment_" + fileCounter
            alert(tempInputId)
            attachmentInput.prop("id",tempInputId)
            attachmentInput.prop("name",tempInputId)
            attachmentInput.appendTo("#hiddenDiv")
            fileCounter ++;
            $("#"+tempInputId).click();

         });
```